# Disable Keycloak user from LDAP

Tags: ldap, keycloak, openldap

I have synchronization between OpenLDAP and Keycloak via user federation, everything works fine(import from LDAP, authentication, etc).
I need to have a possibility to disable Keycloak user from LDAP. I know that it is possible to disable a user from Keycloak, but is there a way to do the same from LDAP? Maybe add some attribute to LDAP record which will be mapped to Keycloak record and user will be disabled.

My goal is: disable authentication for a particular user using LDAP.

Comment: What do you mean by disable authentication for a particular user from LDAP.

Comment: I need to have leverage from LDAP which helps me to disable Keycloak user. Keycloak user has an attribute "User Enabled". How can I change this attribute from LDAP?

Comment: So for instance a user goes to authenticate and that user only exist on LDAP, you want to not allowed that user to authenticate, but that user only exist in the LDAP, right?

Comment: Not quite so. I have synchronization between Keycloak and OpenLDAP. It means that I have the same user in both places.

Comment: I am looking for a way to influence on Keycloak user attribute "User Enabled" from LDAP attribute via mapper. Is there such an option? Here is screen from Keycloak about "User enabled" attribute. https://prnt.sc/wm0kqf

Comment: I got you point, as far I as that will not work with a mapper. Mapper I meant to be read after the user have authenticate

Comment: I've been looking for this as well, probably based on the `locked`-attribute. It's not technically possible at this point. The advice is to write your own mapper. It could be similar to the `MSADUserAccountControlStorageMapper`. If you ever do this, please ping me, it goes beyond what I'm willing to do for it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work with fedora 389.
I created an "enabled" attribute as String and created the corresponding mapper in the federation configuration as "user-attribute-ldap-mapper".
Now when I change the "enabled" switch in keycloak the change is propagated to ldap